# Show horizontal line only when condition runs for second time in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, conditional-rendering

I am trying to show the horizontal line `<hr>` tag, when the conditions render for second time. For example, When the data renders first time, I dont want the `<hr>` tag, but as it renders the second time, I expect hr tag to come between the two data's. I tried but couldn't find anything. Can anyone help me with this

```
{
  this.props.details && this.props.details.length > 0
    ? this.props.details.map((data) => (
        <>
          <div>{data} </div>
        </>
      ))
    : null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, what would be reason you like to have the <hr> from JS. I think same can be achieved using CSS ?

Comment: Even if I Apply css, I want it to get that render after the second time data gets displayed on UI!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply maintain a state say `isSecondRender` and set it to false. In componentDidMount, you can set it to true(i.e. 2nd render).

In jsx, you can conditionally render `hr` tag.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hr-tag-display-2nd-time-render-pqg4j)

**code snippet**

```js
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isSecondRender: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setIsSecondRender();
  }

  setIsSecondRender = () => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.setState(prev => ({
          ...prev,
          isSecondRender: !prev.isSecondRender
        })),
      3000
    );
  };

  render() {
    return this.props.details && this.props.details.length > 0 ? (
      <>
        {!this.state.isSecondRender
          ? "first time rendering"
          : "second time rendering done"}
        {this.props.details.map(data => (
          <>
            <div> {data} </div>
            {this.state.isSecondRender && <hr />}
          </>
        ))}
      </>
    ) : null;
  }
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <MyComp details={["data-1", "data-2"]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```